# Compatibility level 110 not visible

Tags: sql-server, compatibility

I am using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio and trying to use `TRY_CONVERT` like functions in my stored procedures.

I am not able to execute those as I can set the compatibility level for database to 100.

I cannot see the compatibility level 110 in the dropdown menu.

Kindly help solving this problem. Do I need to reinstall the Management Studio for this?

Comment: What **version** of the **database engine** are you running against? Run `SELECT @@VERSION` on your database and see what the output says. Those functions are driven by the **database ENGINE** version - not the Management Studio GUI tool version...

Comment: Hi marc_s,
 the command output says,

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)  Mar 29 2009 10:11:52 
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Comment: @AmeyDeshpande `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST` are only available since SQL Server 2012.

Comment: So it means i need to update the SQL database engine version right?
any idea how to update the same?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what version of the **database engine** are you running against.

Run

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

on your database and see what the output says.

Those functions are driven by the **database ENGINE version** - not the Management Studio GUI tool version.

So with your output:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64) Mar 29 2009 10:11:52 
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )
```

it's clear you're using SQL Server **2008** as the database engine, and the `TRY_CONVERT` function is a new function in SQL Server **2012**, so this is *not available* to you at this time.

You need to download / purchase a newer version of SQL Server and install it either over or side-by-side with the existing SQL Server 2008 instance you have in order to be able to use those new functions.